# System.Web not found?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

I am getting the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm trying to do an LDAP membership configuration in the Web.Config, and asked the question under that earlier, but I think this may be a more general problem. I'm using the Visual Studio Development server in VS2010/.NET 4.0

Edit: Web.Config Shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="FPLMobileWebApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LDAPConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://ad.company.com/CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/FPL/Search" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DomainLoginMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DomainLoginMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web" connectionStringName="LDAPConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <applicationSettings>
    <FPLMobileWebApp.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="FPLMobileWebApp_FPLdb_Parts" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://a09devlab/pld/parts.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </FPLMobileWebApp.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: I simply added the System.Web dll to the bin folder of my application. However, I want to make sure this deploys properly, now it is saying that my connection string does not exist.

Comment: where are you getting the error?

Comment: @DanielA.White I get the error when I try to login(utilize the membership provider) with the function 

    if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName,model.Password))
    //do stuff

In my AccountController, which is responsible for displaying the login page.

Comment: @EmanueleGreco
I have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

**I think it's a permission problem.**
Look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx).

> The **ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider** instance works only in the
>   **full-trust policy** default configuration of ASP.NET. In order to use
>   the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider instance at any partial-trust
>   level, either you must make changes to the appropriate trust policy
>   file for your application or you must create a "sandbox" assembly that
>   is deployed in the GAC.
>   The **ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider** class
>   requires **unrestricted DirectoryServicesPermission permission** to run.
>   This permission is not added to any of the partial-trust policy files
>   supplied with ASP.NET. Although adding the DirectoryServicesPermission
>   permission to a partial-trust policy file will enable use of the
>   ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider class, doing so makes the
>   System.DirectoryServices namespace classes available to any code
>   running in your ASP.NET pages. This option is not recommended for any
>   Web servers that need to run in a secure, locked-down mode.
>   As an
>   alternative, you can create a **"sandbox" assembly that calls the
>   ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider class**. This assembly can contain
>   either a wrapper class that forwards method calls to the
>   ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider class or a class that derives from
>   the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider class. In either case, the
>   wrapper class must assert unrestricted DirectoryServicesPermission
>   permission. Deploy the sandbox assembly in the GAC and mark the
>   assembly with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute (APTCA)
>   attribute. This will enable your partially trusted ASP.NET code to
>   call your wrapper class, and since the wrapper class internally
>   asserts the unrestricted DirectoryServicesPermission permission, your
>   wrapper class will be able to successfully call the provider

So, the easiest way to solve the problem *(if you are really facing a security problem)* is to set **full trust policy** to your application.
How to do it? Look at [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772237%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Interestingly, System.Web wasn't explicitly listed in the Web.Config and the application worked fine. It is only when I tried to add authentication that I got this problem. I tried adding System.Web to the Web.Config and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, this will eventually be deployed to a server, but until then I don't really care if it is secure, what is the easiest way to make it work?

Comment: The easiest way -if it's really a permission problem- is provinding full-trust to your application if it's possible

Comment: I added the following to my Web.Config: 
`<securityPolicy>
 <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
 </securityPolicy>` 
same result